# Run code when calling a missing/undefined function or when evaluating a missing symbol?

Tags: r

Is it possible in R to run some code when calling a missing (yet undefined) function or when evaluating an inexistent symbol?

Or: is there any way to load a library in such a situation?

In the end, I would like to have something like this:

```
autoload.table <- list(foo = source("foo.R"), bar = library("bar"))
foo()
#=> load "foo.R" and evaluate `foo()`
```

**edit:**
Building on the solution by @Miff, I came up with this function, which avoids the string mangling:

```
tAutoload <- function (name, expr) {
    cl <- as.list(match.call())
    sname <- as.character(cl$name)
    if (!exists(sname)) {
        assign(sname,
            eval(substitute(function (...) {
                rm(name)
                expr
                name(...)
            })), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
tAutoload(foo, source("foo.R"))
tAutoload(bar, library("bar"))
```

Upon first invocation, e.g., `foo()` will remove itself and then execute the assigned action.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you expect this to work, but it's not possible. How should R know that `foo` is defined in `foo.R`?

Comment: @Roland That's what the autoload.table would be for.

Comment: If you do this, why not simply load the package (possibly even in your Rprofile.site file)? I don't see the usecase here.

Comment: @Roland: loading unneeded packages takes time.

Comment: So, load them when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how generally applicable this code is - I think it may not be robust to a different types of argument matching in foo and bar, but how about something like this:

```
at <- list(foo = 'source("foo.R")', qplot = 'library(ggplot2)') #too lazy to type autoloader.tablF
for (i in 1:length(at))
  assign(names(at)[i], eval(parse(text=paste0("function(...){ rm(",names(at)[i],",envir=.GlobalEnv);",at[[i]],"; ",names(at)[i],"(...) }")),envir=.GlobalEnv))
```

What does that mess do? For each element in the `at` list, create a function in the global environment, which deletes itself, runs the code from `at[[i]]`, then runs the function again, with the arguments originally used, which should now call the new version loaded. So `foo` now has the value:

```
function(...){ rm(foo,envir=.GlobalEnv);source("foo.R"); foo(...) }
```

Example:

```
> foo
function(...){ rm(foo,envir=.GlobalEnv);source("foo.R"); foo(...) }
> foo(1)
fooing 1 
> foo
function(x) cat("fooing", x, "\n") #Now imported from foo.R
```

or for qplot:

```
> qplot
function(...){ rm(qplot,envir=.GlobalEnv);library(ggplot2); qplot(...) }
> qplot(diamonds$cut, diamonds$carat) #produces a plot
> qplot #now prints definition from ggplot2
```

Comment: Thanks. In order to avoid the string mangling, I came up with this function ... (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank function!

foo <- function(){ }